# rails controller map unknown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, controller

In `authors_controller.rb`, I have this :

```
def show
    a = Author.find(params[:id])
    @author = a.map { |e| e.titlecase }
end
```

I get an error say that map is an undefined method for Author::0x007fec244142a0.

I also tried this :

```
def show
    @author = Author.find(params[:id])
    @author.each { |k, v| v.capitalize  }
end
```

How can I apply the method titlecase to each value of Author.find ?

Comment: What fields are you trying to capitalize?

Comment: each field.....

Answer (score 0):

`find(params[:id])` returns not array, not enumerator and not Relation class but just instance of your model. You can't use `map` or `each` so just apply `titlecase` to returned object.

```
def show
  @author = Author.find(params[:id])
  @author.name = @author.name.titlecase # if you have column 'name'
end
```

But better move titlecased name to model's method or just use `@author.name.titlecase` where it's needed.

You can use `where` and use `map` operator with it:

```
def show
  @author = Author.where(id: params[:id])
```

Comment: So that means that I can't apply any methods to the methods contained in the instance of the class iteratively ?

Comment: You can iterate through all attributes `@author.attributes.each{|k,v| @author[k] = v.capitalize if v.respond_to?(:capitalize)}`

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly but it works. I'm sure there is a better way to do this stuff.

```
@author.attributes.map do |k,v| 
  v = @author.__send__(k).capitalize if @author.__send__(k).respond_to?(:capitalize)
end
@author.save
```

I must say however that I wouldn't recommend doing things this way. Better to capitalize each field in the model

Comment: Yes and no, sometimes it's better and safer to be more explicit. DRY-ing the code is a good general rule, but shouldn't be taken too far. But that is just my opinion, I'm sure others will disagree.

Answer (score 0):

From I understood. You want to capitalize all fields of record `Author.find(params[:id])` right?

First, `Author.find(params[:id])` will return a record, not array. That means you can't use `each` or `map` for it.

To capitalize all fields of a record. Could u try:

```
def show
  author = Author.find(params[:id])
  @author = author.attributes.values.map{|field| field.to_s.capitalize}
end
```

It will return an array of all field values.

**UPDATE 1**

For better

```
def show
  author = Author.find(params[:id])
  @author_info = author.attributes.values.map{|field| field.is_a?(String) ? field.capitalize : field}
end
```

Comment: I would not recommend doing it this way, because it capitalizes everything, even changing stuff like created_at to strings and then capitalizing.

Comment: created_at maybe like `2016-11-04 02:46:23 utc`. I think It's OK, and on his question, he said `How can I apply the method titlecase to each value of Author.find ?`

Comment: One more thing, `@author` is now an array not an instance of `Author`, so you cannot work it like an active record object, saving and updating.

Comment: Why we need to update on `show` action? As I said, may be `thiebo` want to list all infomation of author in an array. I also update to make code better. Plz take a look.

Comment: It's better yes, but you can also use `field.is_a?(String)`. I would still check if it responded to capitalize instead, but like I said these are just my opinions.